# Copy template file to multiple directories, query template files for rename based on directory

Tags: python, list, rename

So I am fairly new to Python and I have scoured the web and stack overflow for a simple solution. I am sure there is a solution I have come across that would work. However I am having a hard time implementing other peoples solutions into the context of what I need.

I have a template file that I have managed to copy into multiple sub directories of my "projStorage" variable.

e.g

```
+ proj\Storage\dir
   + Seq1
       + template.file >> which I want to rename to >> Seq1_stringHere.File
   + Seq2
       + template.file >> Seq2_stringHere.File
   + Seq3
       + template.file >> Seq3_stringHere.File
```

The problem is that I want to rename my template files based on the directory they have just been copied to. To do this I was doing an os.listdir(seqFileList) which I was hoping would return a list with each template file so I could do a rename to the Seq Directory name + a string format.

I have done this using a for loop. Now I understand that my 'seqFileList' is doing a listdir() for each folder in the proj\Storage\Dir and is returning my list of files.
I have seen solutions of 'flattening a list' but I am not quite understanding how that works. 
Printing seqFileList returns something like,

```
['Template.file']
['Template.file']
['Template.file']
```

when what I want is

```
['Template.file','Template.file','Template.file',]
```

so I can rename to

```
['Seq01_strHere.File','Seq02_strHere.File','Seq03_strHere.File',]
```

Also I am aware that the rename part of the code is not implemented yet as I am unsure of how to go about that. I know one solution is the os.rename() however I am not sure of where to properly implement this.

I understand that this question is probably not new and will be remarkably simple for some people. I am not trying to be a "Help Vampire" as I am really trying to internalize this stuff for myself. So please forgive my newness.
Any and all solutions are appreciated.

I have replaced file paths and project names for clarity.

Thanks in advance.

```
import os, shutil

 projTemplate = 'Path\\To\\Template.file'

 projStorage = 'Proj\\Storage\\dir' 

 projSeqs = os.listdir(projStorage)

 for seqs in projSeqs:
  seqFileDir = os.path.join(projStorage, seqs)     
  shutil.copy2(projTemplate, seqFileDir)               
  seqFileList = os.listdir(seqFileDir)

  print seqFileDir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not rename it at the point you're copying the template in your subfolders?

```
for seqs in projSeqs:
    seqFileDir = os.path.join(projStorage, seqs)
    seqFileTemplate = os.path.join(seqFileDir, '%s_stringHere.File' % seqs)
    shutil.copyfile(projTemplate, seqFileTemplate)
    shutil.copystat(projTemplate, seqFileTemplate)
```

Comment: copystat is definitely an added benefit. Thanks so much! Very easy to understand.

Comment: I included it because I believe that's what `shutil.copy2` does over `shutil.copy`, so I thought you must have wanted it :)

Comment: Awesome I thought that is what it did. Thank you for clarifying. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os,shutil
projTemplate = '/Path/To/Template.file'
projStorage = '/Proj/Storage/dir'
[shutil.copy2(projTemplate, os.path.join(projStorage,dir,dir+"_stringHere.file")) 
            for dir in os.listdir(projStorage)]
```

Comment: Super Awesome! Love the quickness on this. I am going to need some practice before I start breaking it down like this.

Comment: Using a list comprehension as a means of flow control is generally frowned upon in Python, as you're effectively building a list that you never use. If you're not constructing a list, then a list comprehension is not the answer, a `for` loop is. If you _must_ have a one-liner: `map(lambda x: shutil.copy2(projTemplate, x), ((os.path.join(projStorage, dir, dir+_'stringHere.file')) for dir in os.listdir(projStorage)))` (although it's obviously nicer if you break it out into partials and helpers)

Comment: @Matthew, I totally agree with you. A for loop will be more clear here. Since Python is the language let me taste blood in Functional Programming after years of Java programming. I can't help write code more functional style(e.g., list comprehension over for loop).Furthermore, list comprehension make me eaier to refactor my code later in case the result is need and a filter need to be added. So I usually prefer list-comprehension over for loop.

Comment: I find I'm the other way around: I more often need to _add_ to a looping construct, for debugging or for additional functionality, so picking apart the clever listcomp I wrote gets tedious. You're also adding to your code the overhead of constructing the list every time, impacting on both speed & memory. I do understand the appeal of a more functional approach, this just isn't the right way to do it. (As an aside, have you read David Beazley's amazing [Generator Tricks for Smart Programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/)? It's jam packed with techniques I think you'll find very useful...)

Comment: Great breakdown! This is the type of stuff I like to find out! :D